# Sencha navigation

Tags: cordova, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have two .JS file in my application. one is for log-In form another is for sign Up form.  have one button for navigate to sign up form? but i don't know how to navigate it from login page to signup page. Thank You!!

Comment: Folks will need more details than that to help you. Please provide more context and sample code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an Ext.Panel with two items like so

```
var panel = Ext.Panel({
    fullscreen: true,
    layout: 'card',
    cardSwitchAnimation: 'fade',
    items: [
        login,
        signup
    ]
});
```

Then you add a handler to a Ext.Button and add the following to it :

```
panel.setActiveItem(signup);
```

Or

```
panel.setActiveItem(login);
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

there are a container called navigationView which is used to switch between views.
there are multiple views in a single application, by navigationView one can switch between multiple views in application.

you can refer some sample code here :

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/example/oreilly

and

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/example/navigation-view

both the example switching views when user tap on any item of a list.
we can achieve switching views by handling tap/itemTap/itemSingleTap/itemDoubleTap or many other events of all the available/supported tools/widgets of sencha touch 2.0.0 .

there are push method of navigation view by implementing it new View will pushed on the screen.

hope you can understand it by following code sample :

```
- take your main view as navigationView .
- put the button into the navigationView .
- write the following code into tap-listener of your button

this.up('your navigationView xtype').push({
     xtype: 'xtype of the view at which you wanna go by button tap'<br>
});
```